# Swift - Draw shapes and use as sprite for a SKSpriteNode (bezier path?)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have shapes (rectangles and circles) that I want to position in the same place on all devices (e.g. 40% along the x and 20% up the y axes).

here is some code:

```
class ColourSprite : SKSpriteNode {

var colour: String
var type: String



init(colour: String, categoryBitMask: UInt32, contactTestBitMask: UInt32,
     collisionBitMask : UInt32, type : String, point1: array, point2: array, point3: array, point4: array) {


    let shape = UIBezierPath()

    shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(point1[0], point1[1]))
    shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(point2[0], point2[1]))
    shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(point3[0], point3[1]))
    shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(point4[0], point4[1]))



    let texture = SKTexture() //I don't know what to do here

    self.colour = colour
    self.type = type

    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())


    if type == "block" {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
    }
    else {
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }
    self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = categoryBitMask
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = contactTestBitMask
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionBitMask
}
```

So I was thinking of passing all the points (which would be in the form of size.height/size.width from the GameScene class) to my SKSpriteNode to class so that It will draw it onto the screen at the correct positions, but i am unsure of how to make the bezier the texture of the sprite, so it can retain its physical properties, any ideas? If that doesn't make any sense let me know too.

Comment: With sprite kit,  you do not need to worry about %.  Scale mode takes care of that to save you the cycles of all that math.  A scene is pretty much a virtual screen,  you can design for one size and let the system handle the rest.

Comment: Do you know somewhere that explains this?

Comment: I have explained it on quite a few questions here, but I do not know of any decent tutorial doing it correctly.  Most of the ones I have seen were from people who didn't quite understand how it works.

Comment: What is your main question? Is it how to get the positioning correct for all devices or is it giving a bezier path a texture? As far as I'm aware, paths don't have textures.

Comment: If you want a filled, textured sprite with the shape of a bezier curve, would an SKCropNode help? Use the path to crop the SKSpriteNode tot he shape you desire.